# Rotel PC-USB for Linux. Any solution or suggestions to try

Tags: drivers, audio

I have a Rotel RA 1570 integrated amplifier that will receive audio files from a PC through a USB connection.

To play files above 96 kHz we need a driver supplied by Rotel. This is available only for Windows (Mac support is native to Mac). I have not been able to find a Linux version, and don't see any interest in a project on the Rotel site or in a Google search.

I think maybe wine, maybe a VM but it seems like this driver is probably a metal-level thing and won't recognize virtual interfaces. I haven't delved much at that depth so am quite ignorant of issues.

What is my best hope here?

Thanks.

Comment: The product page http://rotel.com/de/product/ra-1570 says the device is "USB Audio Class 2" compatible. Allegedly, so are the Linux usb sound drivers (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/usb/format.c mentions UAC_VERSION_2). Can you force usage of the driver with your device by writing to `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/snd-usb-audio/new_id` as illustrated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/forcing-driver-to-device-match ?

Comment: @Hermann So the 96 kHz limit could be because of the requirement for USB2? And not some special Rotel interface. That is interesting. I am already getting good sound quality through Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-28) with the Rotel set to USB2 and no change in drivers. Perhaps we're done? I have no idea how to test so...

Comment: Test: Disconnect Rotel, switch Rotel to different modes (USB2, native, whatever else it has), connect Rotel again. Look at new lines in `dmesg` output (note timestamp). Edit question with output if you don't understand it. This should tell you if Linux provides a driver for the various Rotel modes. You can also interrogate ALSA to show which sample rates are supported, but I have to look this up when I'm at home.

Comment: For this question the only mode we can use is PC-USB. The Sound Preferences dialog shows the Rotel as Analog Stereo Output device. From the journal: ''''Jul 18 07:39:26 acer kernel: hid-generic 0003:278B:3001.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [ROTEL Rotel PC-USB] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input2
Jul 18 07:39:26 acer kernel: input: ROTEL Rotel PC-USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.2/0003:278B:3001.0007/input/input15
''''

Comment: I will come back later and edit the question. Or submit a new question about this. What is the site preference in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://www.epsglobal.com/downloads/XMOS/Why-do-you-need-USB-Audio-Class-2.pdf
```

This is a USB1 audio vs USB2 audio issue. The Rotel windows driver is to add to Windows the USB2 support that Windows does not provide but that Linux and OSX do provide.

So with Linux we do not need the Rotel driver. The Rotel site omits to mention that Linux systems do not need a special Rotel driver. This is probably because Rotel thinks that Linux users are smart enough to not need to be told. What about that?

I await correction.

Comment: Don't forget to tell PulseAudio to allow a higher sample rate and size if you haven't already.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Are you sure that PulseAudio is involved here? If so please explain. My understanding (thin to be sure) is that the USB is to send the sound file to the amplifier's DAC and so on. Am I missing something?